# How to track a invalid pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have my code ready to run with [PROOF](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/proof).

Whenever I run code standalone I works fine, when I activate PROOF, my code crash with a Segmentation Fault.

With GDB I'm able to know exactly where it crashes: when I try to follow a pointer to a object. This makes me think that this pointer (that I'm absolutely sure it was valid before) is invalid and I have no idea why so.

Are there other options? can I track that pointer so I know where it was released?

Comment: you mean it frees already freed pointer?

Comment: Usually, I use valgrind for things like this. If you compile with `-g` and use valgrind's `--track-origins=yes` option, you can find the locations of invalid reads in the code and the locations of uninitialized data.

Comment: @user2533527 no,  at that stage of the program,  that pointer should contain information that is crucial for the program,  so I actually need to use it

Comment: Great! Post any errors it reports. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexReinking I found the function that was freeing my staff :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `valgrind` [memcheck tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html) with `--leak-check=summary --track-origins=yes`.

This shows invalid memory access (Segmentation Fault) and where they had been freed.